# How to implement inline keyboard navigation in Python Telegram program?

Tags: python, telegram

I have written a Python Telegram program but I need a bit of help on navigating the inline keyboard. When user clicks on one of the custom keyboard button [Feedback], an inline keyboard appears:

```
"Message: Do you find this app useful"
[No], [Yes], [Leave Comments].
```

When pressing [No], only a text message appears "Thank you and we hope you can leave some comments how to improve the app", goes back to main menu.

When pressing [Yes], a second inline button message appears with wording "Please vote for this app!" which hyperlinks to external website.

When pressing [Leave Comments], user needs to type in comments which is saved into a database.

My problem is upon pressing any of the 3 inline button, it leads to the same function "insert_UserFeedback".

Part of my codes as follows.

```
keyboard03 = [[InlineKeyboardButton("No", callback_data='no'),
InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data='yes')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("Leave Comments", callback_data='comments')]]
reply_markup03 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard03)
update.message.reply_text('Do you find the app useful?', 
reply_markup=reply_markup03)
user = update.message.from_user
return FEEDBACK
```

## At conv_handler states={

```
FEEDBACK: [MessageHandler(Filters.text,
insert_UserFeedback,
pass_user_data=True),


def insert_UserFeedback(bot, update, user_data):    
user = update.message.from_user
#some codes..
sql10 = "UPDATE `subscribers` SET `feedback`='" + userFeedbackTxt + "', 
`feedbackDate`='" + todaydatestamp + "' WHERE `id`=" + str(user.id) + ";"
cc.execute(sql10)
copp.commit()
copp.close()
update.message.reply_text(user.first_name + ', thank you for your feedback!')
return KEYBOARDVAL
```

So regardless if I choose which inline button I chose, "insert_UserFeedback" is called which then requires user to write a comment, because the program did not know in advance which inline button was selected.

Answer (score 0):

The response object `InlineQuery` has a field `query` where the result of the user action is returned. Check the structure at [Telegram API Inline Query](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery)